# streamlining a series of javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

Is there a better, more concise way to do this:

```
function getTweets(){
                $.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=superfad",

                function(data){
                    tweetsLoaded = true;
                    $.each(data.results, function(i,item){
                        var textPlain = item.text;
                        var textLinked = linkify(textPlain);
                        var textHashed = hashify(textLinked);
                        var textListed = listify(textHashed);

                        function linkify(tweet){
                            return tweet.replace(/(http:\/\/[^\s]*)/g, "<a class='twtr-link' target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
                        }

                        function hashify(tweet){
                            return tweet.replace(/(^|\s+)#(\w+)/gi, function(m, before, hash) {
                                return before + '<a target="_blank" class="twtr-hashtag" href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23' + hash + '">#' + hash + '</a>';
                              });
                        }

                        function listify(tweet) {
                            return tweet.replace(/\B[@＠]([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20})/g, function(m, username) {
                                return '<a target="_blank" class="twtr-atreply" href="http://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=' + username + '">@' + username + '</a>';
                            });
                        }

                        $("#twitter_results").append('<li class="twitter"><img class="twitter_img" src="' + item.profile_image_url + '"/>'+ textListed + '</li>');
                    });
                });
            } //end getTweets
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// define this globally
function stuffify(match, group1, group2) {
  switch (group1 || group2) {
    case 'http':
      return '<a class="twtr-link" target="_blank" href="' + match + '">' + match + '</a>';
    case '#':
      return '<a class="twtr-hashtag" target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(match) + '">#' + match + '</a>'

    case '@':
      return '<a class="twtr-atreply" target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=' +  encodeURIComponent(match) + '">@' + match + '</a>';
    default: 
      return match;
  }
}

function(data){
  tweetsLoaded = true;
  var interestingParts = /(http):\/\/\S+|(#|@)[^\s.,!?;^()\[\]<>{}]+/g;

  $.each(data.results, function(i,item) {
    var newText = item.text.replace(interestingParts, stuffify);

    $("#twitter_results").append('<li class="twitter"><img class="twitter_img" src="' + item.profile_image_url + '"/>'+ newText + '</li>');
  });
}
```

Comment: @JAAulde: Building HTML from strings like this is pretty hideous anyway. :S

Answer (score 2):

I would realign the code such that the text manipulation functions (`linkify`, `hashify`, `listify`) are not inside of the `each` function, nor are they even inside of `getTweets` itself. If it's in `getTweets`, then every time you call that function they have to be redefined.  Worse, inside of the `each` where you had them, those functions are redefined for every item in the returned tweet-set.

Also, there is no need to store the return of each of those functions in it's own var since you only use them once afterward and aren't performing any checks before using them.  Just nest the function calls.

Finally, since you're calling append over and over on the same element (inside the `each`) I pre-queried that element instead of querying for it every time the `each` function is executed

Those changes, along with some things I do for my own performance preferences are exhibited in the code sample pasted below.

There are other things I would do, however I won't show them here--you can see it in my posted answer at [Trouble Converting jQuery Script to Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767704/trouble-converting-jquery-script-to-plugin) -- a question about making a jQuery plugin which does the same ting as your code).  You should store the formatted tweets in an array rather than append each as you get it.  Having built that array, you should then combine it into one string and call append once with that string. Making this a jQuery plugin would also be nice for you as it would not require you modify the code to change the targeted DOM element. Looking into use of `String.prototype.link` would be good as well.

(demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/fQ3Lp/2/ )

```
var getTweets = ( function()
{
    /* Privatized text manipulation functions */
    var linkify = function( tweet )
    {
        return tweet.replace( /(http:\/\/[^\s]*)/g, "<a class='twtr-link' target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\">$1</a>" );
    };

    var hashify = function( tweet )
    {
        return tweet.replace( /(^|\s+)#(\w+)/gi, function(m, before, hash)
        {
            return before + '<a target="_blank" class="twtr-hashtag" href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23' + hash + '">#' + hash + '</a>';
        } );
    };

    var listify = function( tweet )
    {
        return tweet.replace(/\B[@＠]([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20})/g, function(m, username)
        {
            return '<a target="_blank" class="twtr-atreply" href="http://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=' + username + '">@' + username + '</a>';
        } );
    };

    var $twitterResultTarget = $( "#twitter_results" );

    /* The actual function which is stored in `getTweets`   */
    return function()
    {
        $.getJSON( "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=superfad", function( data )
        {        
            tweetsLoaded = true;
            $.each( data.results, function( i, item )
            {
                $twitterResultTarget
                    .append( [
                        '<li class="twitter"><img class="twitter_img" src="',
                        item.profile_image_url,
                        '"/>',
                        listify( hashify( linkify( item.text ) ) ),
                        '</li>'
                    ].join( '' ) );
            } );
        } );
    }
}() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using anonymous functions, its always less confusing if they all have names and are declared outside of any other functions.

Comment: I don't think that answers the question at all, and is not necessarily sound advice.  JS is fairly functional and expressive in nature, and the anonymous function is a large part of what creates that paradigm.

Comment: Its possible that I misunderstood the question, however, just because javascript can use anonymous functions doesn't mean that they don't make the code harder to understand for humans.

Comment: My comment was based on the fact that I took the question to be asking how to make it perform better and more smoothly, not how to make it more human readable. That said, the only 2 anon functions in his code sample are arguments to jQuery functions which generally take anon functions anyway. If you use jQuery enough, I think those make perfect sense.  If you use JS enough, I know that they make perfect sense.  But each has their own style, I do get that.

Comment: Oh, ok, I didn't realize you were asking how to make it perform better.

Comment: I'm not the OP--I could have misinterpreted as well.  Your interpretation could be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably write in in the jQuery plugin style, and use `split` as opposed to `replace` with HTML in callbacks:

```
(function($){

  function getTweets(q) {

    var

      $set = this,

      prefixes = {
        'h': 'h',
        '#': 'http://twitter.com/search?q=%23',
        '@': 'http://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name='
      },

      classes = {
        'h': 'twtr-link',
        '#': 'twtr-hashtag',
        '@': 'twtr-atreply'
      };

    $.getJSON(
      "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=" + encodeURIComponent(q),
      function(data){
        $.each(data.results, function(i, item){

          var
            $li = $('<li class="twitter"></li>')
              .append('<img class="twitter_img" src="' + item.profile_image_url + '"/> ');

          $.each(
            item.text.split(
              /(\s+)|(https?:\/\/[^\s]*)|(#\w+)|(@[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20})/g
            ),
            function(i, chunk) {
              if (/^(https?:\/\/|@|#)/.test(chunk)) {
                $('<a target="_blank"></a>')
                  .addClass(classes[chunk[0]])
                  .attr('href', prefixes[chunk[0]] + chunk.substr(1))
                  .text(chunk)
                  .appendTo($li);
              } else if (chunk) {
                $li.append(document.createTextNode(chunk));
              }
            }
          );

          $li.appendTo($set);

        });
      }
    );

  }

  $.fn.getTweets = getTweets;

})(jQuery);
```

Then call it like this:

```
$('#twitter_results').getTweets('superfad');
```

My $0.02